# Make parallel API calls using Spring boot/java

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing

I am new to spring boot and learning things as they come by. I have a quick question about making parallel API calls.

I have an array of ids that I will be appending to a 3rd party API endpoint and make GET requests and aggregate the data and make a file out of it once all the 3000 calls get completed.

The catch here is the Array will be of size 3000 i.e. I am expected to make 3000 calls. I feel that using a for loop and iterating over 3000 times doesn't make any sense and it is less efficient.

Can anyone please suggest to me the best and efficient way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure third part api support 3000 calls in a small amount of time ?

Comment: Yeah I mean 3000 will not be at once may be we can use batch mechanism like 500 calls at a time and pause and proceed to next 500

Comment: What data do you need to aggregate?

Comment: Few of the fields like comments field, username, id etc. Maximum 5 fields per api call. Every API response has lot of fields but I am only interested in 5 of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Integer> ids = IntStream.range(1, 13).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
int partitionSize = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i += partitionSize) {
    List<Integer> currPartition = ids.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, ids.size()));

    String partitionStr = currPartition.parallelStream() 
            .map(id -> callAPI(id)) // change the aggeragtion according to your needs
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); 

    System.out.println(partitionStr);
}
```